# how to combine plots of shapefiles in one panel and one legend?

Tags: r, shapefile, terra

If we have this shape file from terra package:

```
 library(terra)
 v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
```

I seprate the plaot into three:

```
 plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(49.5, 50))
 plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(50, 50.5))
 plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(49, 49.5))
```

How to show the the three plots in one panel with one legend?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(49.5, 50), legend=F, mar=1)
plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(50, 50.5), legend=F, mar=1)
plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(49, 49.5), plg=list(x="bottomright"), mar=1)
```

[image]

Or something like this

```
layout(rbind(1:4), c(1, 1, 1, 3/4))
plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(49.5, 50), legend=F, mar=1)
plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(50, 50.5), legend=F, mar=1)
plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(49, 49.5), legend=F, mar=1)
plot(v, "NAME_1", col=rainbow(25), border=c("gray"),ylim=c(51, 51.5), mar=1, axes=F, plg=list(x="topleft", cex=1.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add the countries borders?

Comment: and last question please,  under NAME_1, I have NA. how to remove all polygons with NA under NAME_1